# Implementing binary search tree for defaultdict type of collection in python

Tags: python, collections, binary-search-tree, defaultdict

I have googled a code for searching a key in python defaultdict using binary search. I have implemented it as

```
import collections
import bisect

class MyDict(collections.Mapping):
  def __init__(self, contents):
    "contents must be a sequence of key/value pairs"
    self._list = sorted(contents)
  def __iter__(self):
    return (k for (k, _) in self._list)
  def __contains__(self, k):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(self._list, (k, None))
    return i < len(self._list) and self._list[i][0] == k
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self._list)
  def __getitem__(self, k):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(self._list, (k, None))
    if i >= len(self._list): raise KeyError(k)
    return self._list[i][1]


mydictionary = {'60': set(['US0596951063']), '61': set(['']), '63': set(['US3385171059']), '65': set(['US0936981085']), '67': set(['']), '69': set(['']), '24': set(['', 'US0191181082']), '25': set(['']), '26': set(['US0301371037']), '27': set(['US0295951059']), '20': set(['', 'US0320157037', 'US0320151097']), '21': set(['']), '22': set(['']), '23': set(['']), '29': set(['']), '2': set(['']), '6': set(['']), '8': set(['US0077371096']), '99': set(['']), '98': set(['']), '91': set(['US1104481072']), '15': set(['']), '93': set(['']), '92': set(['US0976981045']), '94': set(['', 'US1025651084']), '97': set(['US0885771016']), '96': set(['', 'US0557101070']), '11': set(['']), '10': set(['']), '13': set(['']), '12': set(['US9099121074']), '59': set(['US09247Q1067']), '58': set(['US0576652004']), '17': set(['']), '16': set(['']), '19': set(['IL0006320183']), '54': set(['US0405151087']), '51': set(['']), '50': set(['US05343P1093']), '53': set(['']), '18': set(['US0080153077']), '90': set(['US0682211000']), '88': set(['', 'US0826571079']), '82': set(['US0582641025']), '80': set(['US0571491069']), '81': set(['US0928281023']), '86': set(['', 'US1030431050']), '87': set(['US05564T1034']), '84': set(['US0565251081']), '46': set(['US0303711081']), '47': set(['', 'US00753P1030', 'US00163U1060']), '45': set(['US22149T1025', 'US2274781044']), '42': set(['US2947007033']), '40': set(['US61747Y6914']), '41': set(['', 'US8814482035']), '5': set(['US0245914066', 'US0245911096']), '7': set(['US0048161048']), '9': set(['US0063513081']), '76': set(['US0905722072']), '74': set(['LR000A0D81P7']), '72': set(['US0668491006']), '71': set(['CA08135F1071']), '102': set(['US1484111018']), '100': set(['US13971R3066']), '101': set(['US1330341082']), '79': set(['']), '78': set(['']), '33': set(['', 'US00215F1075', 'US0490792050']), '32': set(['', 'US0373471012']), '31': set(['']), '30': set([''])}

d = MyDict(mydictionary)
r = d.__getitem__('84')
print r
```

i'm newbie to python and algorithms, can anyone help me please.

I am getting this below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 24, in <module>
    i = d.__getitem__('84')
  File "search.py", line 17, in __getitem__
    if i >= len(self._list): raise KeyError(k)
KeyError: '84'
```

Comment: _"contents must be a sequence of key/value pairs"_. A dict is not a sequence of pairs, it's a mapping.

Comment: is there any alternative solution for dictionary? @Rawing

Comment: `MyDict(mydictionary.items())`

Comment: @Rawing thank you it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass a dictionary to your `__init__`:

```
self._list = sorted(contents)
```

Then `self._list` is a list of the *keys* of the `dict`:

```
In [5]: my_dict
Out[5]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [6]: list(my_dict)
Out[6]: ['a', 'b']

In [7]: sorted(my_dict)
Out[7]: ['a', 'b']
```

So now your `self._list` attribute is a list of strings, but then in `__getitem__`:

```
 i = bisect.bisect_left(self._list, (k, None))
```

You try to bisect it with a tuple, `('84', None')` forcing a comparison between a string and a `tuple`, but in Python 2, unfortunately, *this is allowed and always evaluates a string as less than a `tuple`*.

From the Python 2 [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

> **CPython implementation detail**: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Thus, consider:

```
In [7]: sorted(my_dict)
Out[7]: ['a', 'b']

In [8]: import bisect

In [9]: _list = sorted(my_dict)

In [10]: bisect.bisect_left(_list, ('a', None))
Out[11]: 2
```

Since your `tuple` automatically evaluates to greater than everything in your list, it returns `len(self._list)`. Thus triggering your condition to `raise KeyError`.

To get a sequence of key/value pairs from a dictionary, use:

```
mydictionary.items()
```

Note, in Python 3, order comparisons between different types is not generally allowed. Instead, a `TypeError` is thrown, which would have been more helpful:

```
<ipython-input-1-8101e6bd7098> in __getitem__(self, k)
     14     return len(self._list)
     15   def __getitem__(self, k):
---> 16     i = bisect.bisect_left(self._list, (k, None))
     17     if i >= len(self._list): raise KeyError(k)
     18     return self._list[i][1]

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Hey @juanpa.arrivillage, thank you for the detailed explanation. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def __getitem__(self, k):
    # i = bisect.bisect_left(self._list, (k, None))
    i = bisect.bisect_left(self._list, k)
    if i >= len(self._list): raise KeyError(k)
    return self._list[i][1]
```

you're search self._list, which is a list of keys ["84",...] for an item ("84",None), which does not exist.

Comment: checked after changing but getting r as 4, which is wrong.